# How to debug dart code in firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

First, it is possible to write firebase cloud functions in dart.
For that we need

1. write cloud functions using https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop
2. compile dart to js code
3. move compiled code to firebase functions folder
4. then run firebase emulators as usual

Is it possible to set breakpoints in dart code in the firebase functions emulator?

## My use case

#### using this library https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop

I want to port my firebase functions from **TypeScript** to **Dart** but one of the concerns I have now is **debugging**
How I can debug dart code in the firebase emulator?

In my **typescript** project
I run this command `tsc -w | firebase emulators:start --only functions --inspect-functions`
and can set breakpoints in VSCode

But how it will work with https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop in dart?

Comment: What do you mean with port from TypeScript to Dart? Firebase functions cannot be writen in Dart, as you can see here in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/functions/code/languages). To your question, I have found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K35cmKBEszU) that has a Flutter app with Firebase Functions in TypeScript being debug in VSCode, would this be what your are looking for?

Comment: I updated my question but now you can with the help of https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop